# Loading data dynamically in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with fixed header and scrollable rows part. The row data comes from backend and its based on what the user gives input in a provided search box. Based on the input of the search box the table is populated with rows. For front end optimization,I want to bring all the data from backend and show only first 10 rows in view and the rest data should be shown as the user scrolls down in the table.

Is there any way to achieve a scenario like this ?

Comment: Take a look at Datatables https://datatables.net/ , I think it covers your needs.

Comment: you should use datatable jquery plugins which will fulfill all your requirement. https://datatables.net/

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar  Yes, I know about the datatables but designing datatables is bit difficult. So i want to achieve it through custom written javascript or jquery function.

Comment: yeah, using infinite scrolling with saving data in frond end db!

Comment: @Dhiren any examples or fiddle to show the demo for the solution you just told ?

Comment: @nikSharma but even try not to load all data on front end side as this will create thick client problems such as crashing ,etc.. try to filter data from database side only.

Answer (score 1):

So you can use something similar to infinite scroll pagination in the frontend, whenever you reach the end of the page append the data from the `API` to the existing table data. Whenever you reach the end of the page new data will be added to the table.

```
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
  if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
    //Add your data append logic here
  }
};
```

Does this help?

Comment: @nikSharma try this way for frond end side and query back end DB for next batch of dats in if condition.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is a scenario doing that. If datatables.net can do it you can write a custom code who can do the same. It will require some time and alot of testing though (especially cross-browser testing).

First of you would have to fetch the data from the Backend (preferably from an API) and save it into a javascript readable format (recommended: JSON).

```
[
  {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "dob": "01.01.1990",
    "job": "Manager"
  },
  ...
]
```

Then you have to write a javascript function that can output the object into the correct table-rows

For the part of showing more content after scrolling down, you'd have to write an event listener that recognises the expected scroll and starts a new ajax-request as stated above

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using AJAX. Use below example code and adjust as per your requirement:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">  
<div id="scrollbox" >  
    <div id="content" >  
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>  
        <p>Ipsum lorem dolor amet sit</p>  
        <p>Dolor lorem ipsum amet tis</p>  
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>  
        <p>Ipsum lorem dolor amet sit</p>  
        <p>Dolor lorem ipsum amet tis</p>  
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>  
        <p>Ipsum lorem dolor amet sit</p>  
        <p>Dolor lorem ipsum amet tis</p>  
    </div>  
</div>  
<p><span id="status" ></span></p>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
 width:400px;
 margin:0px auto;
 padding:40px 0;
}
#scrollbox {
 width:400px;
 height:300px;
 overflow:auto; overflow-x:hidden;
}
#container > p{
 background:#eee;
 color:#666;
 font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:0.75em;
 padding:5px; margin:0;
 text-align:rightright;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('document').ready(function(){  
  updatestatus();  
  scrollalert();  
});  
function updatestatus(){  
  //Show number of loaded items  
  var totalItems=$('#content p').length;  
  $('#status').text('Loaded '+totalItems+' Items');  
}  
function scrollalert(){  
  var scrolltop=$('#scrollbox').attr('scrollTop');  
  var scrollheight=$('#scrollbox').attr('scrollHeight');  
  var windowheight=$('#scrollbox').attr('clientHeight');  
  var scrolloffset=20;  
  if(scrolltop>=(scrollheight-(windowheight+scrolloffset)))  
   {  
     //fetch new items  
     $('#status').text('Loading more items...');  
     $.get('new-items.html', '', function(newitems){  
        $('#content').append(newitems);  
        updatestatus();  
    });  
   }  
 setTimeout('scrollalert();', 1500);  
}
```

Check this for more information: http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/create-a-dynamic-scrolling-content-box-using-ajax/